# How to change the separator in the Webix multiSelectFilter?

Tags: javascript, filter, multi-select, separator, webix

The separator in Webix multiSelectFilter is ',' by default. For instance, I need to change this default separator to '/'. Is there a way to change the it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Webix 2.2 you can use separator property next to a filter configuration. Something like next

```
header:{ content:"multiSelectFilter", separator:";" }
```

Full sample can be checked by the next link 
http://webix.com/snippet/e3ed3929